# Are references to UIImage objects kept in memory?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

When is an UIImage really in memory? If I have this:

```
let image = UIImage(named: ...)
```

Can it cause an out of memory exception, if I have for example multiple large images stored like that in an array? Should I only store the names of the images so it doesn't occupy (that much) memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImage(named:)` does cache images, however unreferenced images are purged from the cache automatically if iOS detects a low memory condition.

Generally speaking, this is something you don't need to worry much about unless your app actually is experiencing memory problems and you've profiled it and found issues specifically with your use of images.